# I tried using the Url launcher

Tags: android, flutter

```
return ListTile(
  title: GestureDetector(
    onTap: () async {
      String youtubeUrl =
          "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=$videoURL";
      if (await canLaunch(youtubeUrl)) {
        await launch(youtubeUrl);
      } else {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
          content: Text(
              "Couldn't open the YouTube video. Check the URL or your device settings."),
        ));
      }
    },

When I try tapping on the url is showing "Couldn't open the YouTube video.
```

I was expecting it to launch the youtube url either by opening on the app or web

The url is Correct and is working if i copy it and paste on my chrome[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4YnY.png) that is what is showing in my console when I tap on the url

Answer (score 2):

For Android, you have to specify `https` scheme in your `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` like this:

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    ...
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
```

For iOS, inside `ios/Runner/Info.plist` add this key-array:

```
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        ...
        <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>https</string>
        </array>
```

The need of these configurations is mentioned in the [package description](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher#configuration), however it doesn't give enough example to configure for `https` scheme so you can take the example from this answer as a guide.

Comment: Thank you it has worked, but it do take time before it launch the url

Answer (score 0):

The url is actually invalid.

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=...
```

Skip setting the base url:

```
String youtubeUrl = videoURL;
if (await canLaunch(youtubeUrl)) {
  await launch(youtubeUrl);
}
```